# GraphQL dynamic query building

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-tag

I have a GraphQL server which is able to serve timeseries data for a specified source (for example, sensor data). An example query to fetch the data for a sensor might be:

```js
query fetchData {
    timeseriesData(sourceId: "source1") {
      data {
        time
        value
      }
    }
}
```

In my frontend, I want to allow the user to select 1 or more sources and show a chart with a line for each one. It seems like this would be possible by using a query like this:

```js
query fetchData {
    series1: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source1") {
      data {
        time
        value
      }
    }
    series2: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source2") {
      data {
        time
        value
      }
    }
}
```

Most GraphQL tutorials seem to focus on static queries (e.g. where the only thing that is changing is the variables, but not the actual shape of the request) - but in my case I need the *query itself* to be dynamic (one timeseriesData request for each of my selected ids).

I have the following constraints:

1. Modifying the server's schema is not an option (so I can't pass an array of IDs to the resolver, for example)
2. My query is specified using a template string e.g. gql`...`
3. I don't want to have to manually build up the query as a string, because that seems like a recipe for disaster and would mean that I lose all tooling benefits (e.g. autocomplete, syntax highlighting, linting)

The stack I'm using is:

- Apollo client (specifically apollo-angular)
- Angular
- TypeScript
- graphql-tag (for defining queries)

Ideally, what I want to do is have some way of merging two queries into one, so that I can define them as per the first example but then join them together in an abstraction layer so that I get a single query like the second example to be sent over the wire.

However I'm not sure how to achieve this because graphql-tag is parsing the query into an AST and I'm struggling to understand whether it's feasable to manipulate the query in this way.

**What techniques are there for generating a dynamic query like this, where the *shape* of the query is not known upfront?**

Answer (score 29):

GraqhQL provides directives for this very purpose.

Create a fragment to define common fields, use `@include(if: Boolean)` and `@skip(if: Boolean)` directives on that fragment to get dynamic fields. By dynamic fields we mean fields that are known at execution time.

According to spec, it is best to avoid manual string interpolation to construct dynamic queries.

Directives<sup>[1](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives)</sup> make it possible to include or skip a field based on a boolean expression passed as a query variable. A directive can be attached to a field or fragment inclusion, and can affect execution of the query in any way the server desires.

```
query Hero($episode: Episode, $withFriends: Boolean!) {
  hero(episode: $episode) {
    name
    friends @include(if: $withFriends) {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And in variables:

```
{
  "episode": "JEDI",
  "withFriends": false
}
```

Of course you can send named queries as you did in your second example. Clients will batch the requests automatically.

Comment: @Matt Wilson did you ever come up with a solution to this? I am in the same situation. I've got an array of ID's from another service and for each i need to call a graphql query and looking to call them either as 1 or in batches

Comment: @Mr.7 Hi, I am using Apollo and Apollo Client and found this "BatchHttpLink" its a method. I put my solution here:

https://koala-moon.com/vue-js-apollo-set-up-with-batch-query-processing/

And Apollo Docs:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/batch-http/

On the client side you are just creating a new connection to the (Apollo) graphql server that waits a length of time before sending the request or requests in a batch. Its been handling 100's of user quieries over the last few months with no issues

Comment: Thanks @user3067684 I'll have a look at it :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you could use [fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) for this! But you still have to write 2 `"queries"` in this case `fragments`.

First let's create a `fragment` for each `timeSeries`, please check your timeSeries query type, I'm going to refer to it as `timeseriesDataQuery`

```js
const series1Q = gql`
  fragment series1 on timeseriesDataQuery {
    series1: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source1") {
      data {
        time
        value
      }
    }
  }
}

const series2Q = gql`
  fragment series2 on timeseriesDataQuery {
    series2: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source2") {
      data {
        time
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then just stitch them up in the query:

```js
export const mainQuery = gql`
    query fetchData {
      ...series1 
      ...series2
    }
    ${series1Q}
    ${series2Q}
`
```

Comment: quick question, if I have multiple fragments, which I don't know the length, can I construct the mainQuery this way? like, dynamically add multiple fragments into the query?

Comment: @Evilsanta, as long as you define de fragments and their reference in the main query dynamically, I think it is possible.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have no choice except using String features when the user chooses sensors dynamically and even you don't know sensors on development time (not run-time).

```js
const mainQuery = gql
  `query fetchData($sourceId: String!) {
    timeseriesData(sourceId: $sourceId) {
      data {
        time
        value
      }
    }
  }`;

const mainQueryStr = mainQuery.loc.source.body;
```

The `mainQueryStr` is the string value of your query (to handle dynamicity of your problem)
Then loop on the sensors and replace `$sourceId` with the id of each sensor

```js
// You have to remove the query wrapper first
// Then replace sensor id
const sensorsQueries = sensors.map(sid => mainQueryStr
  .split(`\n`)
  .slice(1, 7)
  .replace(`$sourceId`, sid)
)
```

Then you should join sensorQueries and make new GraphQL query

```js
const finalQuery = gql`
  query fetchData {
    ${sensorsQueries.join(`\n`)}`
  };
```

In this case, you can use tooling benefits like autocomplete, syntax highlighting and  ...
for the `mainQuery` query, not `finalQuery` (Because of you create this one dynamically)

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the query is just a string. You can use simple template literals to achieve your dynamic query.

```js
const generateQuery = () => {
  let query = ""

  for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    const series = `series${i}`
    const source = `source${i}`

    query += `
      ${series}: timeseriesData(sourceId: "${source}") {
        prices
        queried
      }
    `
  }

  return query
}

const fetchDataQuery = gql`
  query fetchData {
    ${generateQuery()}
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone feeling like string operations in not the state-of-the-art way to handle coding there is a library for programmatic query building for GraphQL: [gql-query-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gql-query-builder).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run multiple post using GRAPHQL by splitting the first function response and passing the value to the second function by dynamically created query of GRAPHQL.

### **mainQueries.ts**

```
export const generalLandingPageBySlugQuery: string = `
query ($slug: String!, $isPreview: Boolean = false, $locale: String!) {
  templateGeneralLandingPageCollection(where: {slug: $slug}, locale: $locale, preview: $isPreview, limit: 1) {
    items {
      title
      slug
      metadata {
        ...metadataFields
      }
      components: componentsCollection(limit: 10) {
        items {
          __typename
          ... on TextCardsComponent {
            ...textCardsFields
          }
          ... on TwoColumnImageTextComponent {
            ...twoColumnImageTextFields
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} ${metadataFields}
${components.twoColumnImageText}
${components.accordion}
`;
```

### **Fragments.ts**

```
export const components = {
textCards: `fragment textCardsFields on TextCardsComponent {
    rtHeading: heading {
      json
    }
    backgroundColor
    links: linksCollection {
      items {
        title
        url
        openInNewTab
      }
    }
  }`,
  twoColumnImageText: `
  fragment twoColumnImageTextFields on TwoColumnImageTextComponent {
    rtTitle:title {
      json
    }
    variant
    backgroundColor
    rtHeading: heading {
      json
    }
    rtBlurb: blurb {
      json
    }
    cta {
      title
      url
      openInNewTab
    }
    eyebrow
    cardTitle
    cardDescription
    cardLink
    image {
      ...assetFields
    }
    videoType
    videoId
  }`,
```

### ***Angular Service.ts***
**Function one**

```
   generalLandingPageBySlug(slug: string) {
        const queryVariables = JSON.stringify({
          slug,
          isPreview: this.isPreview,
          locale: this.coreService.locale.code,
        });
    
        return this.http
          .post<ContentfulApiResponse>( // REQUEST ONE
            environment.local ? LOCAL_GRAPHQL : `${GRAPHQL}/general-lp-${slug}`,
            {
              query: Utils.compressGraphQl(generalLandingPageBySlugQuery),
              variables: queryVariables,
            }
          )
          .pipe(
            map((response: ContentfulApiResponse) => {
              this.typename =
                response.data.templateGeneralLandingPageCollection?.items[0].components.items;
    
              //Components Lists
              const currentComponents = [
                ...new Map(
                  this.typename.map((obj: any) => [JSON.stringify(obj), obj])
                ).values(),
              ];
    
              this.typename = currentComponents;
              const choosenComponents = this.typename.map(function (typeName: {
                __typename: any;
              }) {
                return typeName.__typename;
              });
             
                 //Dynamic Query
                  const queryData = 
                'query ($slug: String!, $isPreview: Boolean = false, $locale: String!) {' +
                'templateGeneralLandingPageCollection(where: {slug: $slug}, locale: $locale, preview: $isPreview, limit: 1) {' +
                'items {' +
                'title ' +
                'slug ' +
                'metadata {' +
                '...metadataFields' +
                '}' +
                'components: componentsCollection(limit: 15) {' +
                'items {' +
                '__typename ' +
                (choosenComponents.includes('TextCardsComponent')
                  ? '... on TextCardsComponent {...textCardsFields}'
                  : '') +
                (choosenComponents.includes('TwoColumnImageTextComponent')
                  ? '... on TwoColumnImageTextComponent {...twoColumnImageTextFields}'
                  : '') +
                '}' +
                '}' +
                '}' +
                '}' +
                '}' +
                'fragment metadataFields on Metadata{title metaTitle keyword description facebookType image{...assetFields}canonical noIndex} ' +
                (choosenComponents.includes('TextCardsComponent')
                  ? 'fragment textCardsFields on TextCardsComponent{rtHeading:heading{json}backgroundColor links:linksCollection{items{title url openInNewTab}}}'
                  : '') +
                (choosenComponents.includes('TwoColumnImageTextComponent')
                  ? 'fragment twoColumnImageTextFields on TwoColumnImageTextComponent{rtTitle:title{json}variant backgroundColor rtHeading:heading{json}rtBlurb:blurb{json}cta{title url openInNewTab}eyebrow cardTitle cardDescription cardLink image{...assetFields}videoType videoId}'
                  : '') +
                 ';
              return queryData;
            }),
            mergeMap((payload) => {
              return this.generalFinalData(payload, slug);
            })
          );
      }
```

### **Function Two**

```
  generalFinalData(payload: string, slug: string) {
    const queryVariables = JSON.stringify({
      slug,
      isPreview: this.isPreview,
      locale: this.coreService.locale.code,
    });
    return this.http
      .post<ContentfulApiResponse>( // REQUEST TWO
        environment.local ? LOCAL_GRAPHQL : `${GRAPHQL}/general-lp-${slug}`,
        {
          query: Utils.compressGraphQl(payload),
          variables: queryVariables,
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        map((response: ContentfulApiResponse) => {
          let contentfulResponse: ContentfulResponse = {
            __typename: '',
            pageData: {},
            components: [],
          };
          return this.hasError(
            response,
            response.data.templateGeneralLandingPageCollection
          )
            ? contentfulResponse
            : this.buildData(
                this.unwrapResponse(
                  response.data.templateGeneralLandingPageCollection
                ),
                contentfulResponse
              );
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try the `json-to-graphql-query`. A simple module that takes a JavaScript object and turns it into a GraphQL query to be sent to a GraphQL server.

E.g.:

```
import { jsonToGraphQLQuery } from 'json-to-graphql-query';

const query = {
    query: {
        Posts: {
            id: true,
            title: true,
            post_date: true,
            secret: false, // ta-dam!
            author: {
              __directives: {
                include: {
                  if: new VariableType('show'),
                },
              },
            }
        }
    }
};
const graphql_query = jsonToGraphQLQuery(query, { pretty: true });
```

Resulting `graphql_query`

```
query {
    Posts {
        id
        title
        post_date
        author @include(if: $show)
    }
}
```